# Swiss rail pass for this itinerary?

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland

Does the Swiss Rail multipass make sense for this itinerary?

Will the swiss rail pass cover travel slightly across the border into Italy? (Luino?)

I have an itinerary like this:

- Day 1: Fly into Zurich. Travel directly to Luino (Italy)
- Day 3: Travel to Geneva
- Day 5: Travel to Sigriswil

**Stay in Sigriswil**

- Day 11: Take Jungfrau Railway
- Day 12: Travel to Zurich
- Day 13: Fly out of Zurich

Comment: Which route will you take from Luino to Geneva?

Comment: i don't have a specific route in mind. which is best?

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open.  It's not a price-shopping question; it's a "does this product exist" question.  Asking "is there a tool for putting picture hooks into a wall" is not the same as asking about the price of such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option will be a 4 day Swiss Flexi Pass (http://www.swisspasses.com/railpass/flexi/) with the optional Half-fare Card. This will cover Zurich to Luino (Day 1), Luino to Geneva (Day 2), Geneva to Sigriswil (Day 3). Half-Fare travel from Sigriswil to Jungfraujoch and back, Sigriswil to Zurich (Day 4). You would then get 50% travel from Zurich HB to the airport.

Comment: Are you sure about Luino. Is the pass covering the Italian part? According to http://www.swissrailways.com/sites/default/files/upload/documents/uebersichtskarte_2017_en.pdf he will need to buy a ticket (with discount) from the border to Luino.

Comment: this is one of the main reasons i wanted to ask advice...

Comment: I just asked because if you travel via Locarno it will be covered by the pass. Going around the lake in Italy will be different. I would suggest to go back to Switzerland (Locarno) then Domodosdola and back to Switzerland through Simplon.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be beneficial. From what I can tell, individual tickets are less than the cost of the flexi pass plus half fare card. 1 Adult 7 June 2017 4 Days - 2nd Class with Half Fare Card $ 427.0